# How can Apex update Custom Metadata Types records/Literals values?

Tags: salesforce, metadata, apex

I have a custom metadata type "Project Literals" which have records that contain custom field ids

example:
Label: StatusFieldId
Name: StatusFieldId
Id Field: 00N8E000000XYuM

Using DML statements give me an error "Id Field is not writable"

Is there a way to update the value using apex? maybe by using Metadata API, but how?

Comment: Can you please provide the snippet of code to understand what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Custom Metadata Types Implementation Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/7/en-us/sfdc/pdf/custom_metadata_types_impl_guide.pdf) (page 9, emphasis mine):

> ### Access Custom Metadata Types and Records
>
> Use SOQL to access your custom metadata types and to retrieve the API names of the records on those types. *DML operations aren’t allowed on custom metadata in Apex, the Partner APIs, and Enterprise APIs.*

Answer (score 2):

To make DML-like operations, you might also be interested in the apex/visualforce [Custom Metadata Loader](https://github.com/forcedotcom/CustomMetadataLoader) by Salesforce. It's open source on GitHub and has to make use of the Metadata API behind the scenes.

Related question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110482/can-we-update-records-of-custom-metadata-type-in-visualforce-page